# My Circle Collider 2D can't pass through Edge Collider 2D

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make Flappy Bird, but when I put an `EdgeCollider2D`on the Pipe, the bird can't pass through the collider and gets stuck.

Bird code:

```csharp
{
    Rigidbody2D Rb;
    public float jumpForce;
    
    float score; 
    
    void Start()
    {
        Rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag=="Point")
        {
            score++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to set one of the colliders as a trigger, if you want the other one to pass through it without being blocked?

Comment: You want to go through the pipe? Isn't the goal of the game to not hit them?

Comment: @Zibelas I believe he means a collider in between the pipes, which gives points when collided with.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am understanding your question, you are trying to give the player a point when he collides with the collider in between the pipes. Just simply add the “Point” tag to your GameObject with the EdgeCollider2D attribute. Then, set the **IsTrigger** box to checked. This makes it trigger the `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)` method on collision instead of colliding with the player.